# Sharing display Ubuntu 22.04 with old android tablet

Tags: android, vnc, xrdp, rdp, desktop-sharing

**Problem:** Sharing display Ubuntu 22.04 with old android (4.2.2) tablet don`t work:

Error code: 0x207 (from RD Client tablet side).
The same from aRDP Secure RDP Client.

**What is try to do:**
Info about sharing from [here](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/06/use-ipad-as-second-monitor-ubuntu-22-04).
From android **13** smartphone - no problem with RD Client and sharing display ( but little screen :) ).
Trying **xrdp** server. It`s work with tablet.
But connection only for second user in a separate space. Need exactly share display for current user like extend display work space.
Trying **Deskreen** - as no strange but even work via opera, but little bit laggy.
Trying **VNC** variant but its like clonning display - need to extend.

**Opinion:**
Looks like ssl, tls version compatibility problem. New, fresh from Ubuntu 22.04 side and an old from tablet side. So maybe need some tweaking from Ubuntu 22.04 desktop side (add suport old ssl version or something). The problem is RDP sharing built-in into Gnome for Ubuntu 22.04 and cant find any extended settings for it. Looks like its ex **vino** server but no configs.
Only this:

```
$ grdctl status
RDP:
    Status: enabled
    TLS certificate: /home/user/.local/share/gnome-remote-desktop/rdp-tls.crt
    TLS key: /home/user/.local/share/gnome-remote-desktop/rdp-tls.key
    View-only: no
    Username: (hidden)
    Password: (hidden)
VNC:
    Status: disabled
    Auth method: prompt
    View-only: no
    Password: (hidden)

$ openssl ciphers -v | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq
SSLv3
TLSv1
TLSv1.2
TLSv1.3
```

So may be need some tricks with rdp-tls.crt, rdp-tls.key. Don't think its possible to upgrade support for new ssl, tls for old tablet but may be possible to add old versions for Ubuntu 22.04 or even turn off encrypted connection for rdp server (but how?).

Any suggestion?

Comment: See links like https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/06/use-ipad-as-second-monitor-ubuntu-22-04 and https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/uz5as7/gnome_has_made_it_super_simple_to_extend_your/. The key setting is `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.remote-desktop.rdp screen-share-mode extend`

Comment: @ckhan As you can see I provide the link "Info about sharing" so already activate extend screen share mode.  And no problem with sceen sharing with new 13 android smartphone. Problem with old tablet.